# Scroll the autosize textview after text reaches minimum size

Tags: android, textview

I achieve auto resizing of the text with

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" 
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="40sp"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

in the textview.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html

I want that after text reaches its minimum size if further text is appended, textview should scroll. Example, Calculator app in Android.

I have tried with nesting the textview with horizontalscrollView but have not achieved the desired result yet.

Comment: Hi,  I have the same exact problem... Did you find out the solution for this ?